# Unable to get updated Purchase object after Acknowledging the purchase in new Google billing Api 2.0

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing

I am implementing the new **billing API 2.0** which has this purchase acknowledge method. 
Earlier i was using AIDL for my purchase and i had following use case is that i used to pass developer payload during initiating purchase and used to get back my developer payload in the response as a part of purchase object.

```java
Bundle bundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, "com.example.myapp",
   MY_SKU, "subs", developerPayload);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = bundle.getParcelable(RESPONSE_BUY_INTENT);
if (bundle.getInt(RESPONSE_CODE) == BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
   // Start purchase flow (this brings up the Google Play UI).
   // Result will be delivered through onActivityResult().
   startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent, RC_BUY, new Intent(),
       Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
}
```

and in my on on activity result i used to get purchase object

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
   if (requestCode == 1001) {           
      int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
      String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
      String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");

      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
            String sku = jo.getString("productId");
            alert("You have bought the " + sku + ". Excellent choice, 
               adventurer!");
          }
          catch (JSONException e) {
             alert("Failed to parse purchase data.");
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
   }
}
```

This purchase object has a developer payload which i send to the server for verification.

Now in the new API the developer payload can be added only after purchase is completed or when we consume a purchase, so the **problem is after purchase is acknowledged i need the updated purchase object but how to get it**?

```java
 if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {
            AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                    .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                    .setDeveloperPayload(/* my payload */)
                    .build();
            client.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener);
        }
```

In *acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener* i get only the response code whether it is success or failure. But i need to updated purchase object object with **developerPayload** and **isAcknowledged** flag true.

Is there a way to do so? Could not find anything in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The local cache of purchases is updated by the time your acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener is called so you can query the purchase from the cache using https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.html#querypurchases. We will consider adding the update purchase to the listener for a future library release to make this more convenient.